# How many total times will "i" and "1s" be printed in this recursion function using Master Theorem

Tags: recursion, tree

```
Function f(n):
 if(n>=1)
    for i=1 to n:
       print(i)
 f(n/2)
 f(n/2)
```

a)how many numbers will be printed
b) how many times will 1 be printed
Give your answers as a function of n. You can use the notation Θ(·) if it suits you. In each case, find the recursive relation
of the required numbers and use the Master Theorem to solve it. We can assume that n=2^k, with k>=1.

i know that T(n)=2T(n/2)+ n
and i found the time complexity
for k=1: k=logb(a), then T(n) = Θ(n^k * log(n))=Θ(n*log(n))
for κ>1: k>logb(a), then T(n)= Θ(n^k)
after that i m pretty much done i dont know what to do or how to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track.

In a), the recurrence relation is `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n`, because we print n numbers per iteration. Using the Master Theorem, we see that n = n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup> = n<sup>log<sub>2</sub>2</sup> since a = 2, b = 2. Then, `T(n) = Θ(n*log(n))` as you mentioned.

Hence, `Θ(n*log(n))` numbers will be printed as a function of n.

In b), we note that for every iteration only one 1 will be printed, so the recurrence relation is `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1`. Using the Master Theorem, we see that 1 = n<sup>0</sup> < n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>, so we have `T(n) = Θ(n)`.

Hence, `Θ(n)` 1s will be printed as a function of n.

Comment: I am confused because when I visualize and draw the tree (for example when n=8 and then it has 2 children 4 and 4 and each child had 2 others etc) the number that I count is higher and I don't get why it's not the same

Comment: Also, Θ(n) wouldn't it be for the last level of leaves? Isn't 1 printed all the time even if n is higher and other numbers are also printed with it, not only on the last level

Comment: The essence of big O notation is that it is asymptotically equivalent, that is for large n it will have approximately the same value. For your case, it doesn't necessarily have to have the same number, but rather it is on the same order of magnitude.

i.e. 2n = Θ(n) = 4n = Θ(n) = 4n + c

Comment: you are so correct I ve been cracking my head for hours that I forgot the basicslol . Thank you so much!